# [soql].something not behaving as expected

Tags: soql, list

The following query fails with this error message:

> Illegal assignment from Account to List

```
list <account> actlist =  [select   account.id from contact ].account;
```

The following query is successful but I want all the accounts, not just 1...

```
list <account> actlist =  new list <account>{[select   account.id from contact limit 1].account};
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there anything I can do to the first statement to get all of the accounts into variable actlist? I tried syntax like  `list <account> actlist =  [[select   account.id from contact ].account];` and  `list <account> actlist =  [select   account.id from contact ].account[];`
2. Is there any way I can select from CONTACT and end up with a list of ACCOUNTs in a single line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your questions, if you want to query all `Account` records which have a child `Contact`, the correct approach would be a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join):

```
List<Account> records = [
    SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT AccountId FROM Contact
    )
];
```

No matter what you do, the type of `List` you get back is going to match your top-level `FROM` clause. If you want to assign a query result directly to a `List<Account>`, you need to query `Account` directly. Full stop.

As mentioned in the other answers already, if you want to include `Contact` data, you would use a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join). These two types of join can be used in the same query:

```
List<Account> records = [
    SELECT Name, (SELECT Name FROM Contacts)
    FROM Account WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT AccountId FROM Contact
    )
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get but based on number of accounts in your account, you might hit [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).
With below code, you can retrieve up to 50000 records. If you have more accounts than that, you will get below error

```
too many query rows :50001
```

**Code:**

```
list <account> actlist =  [select  id,(select name,mailingcity from contacts) from account limit 200];
```

If you want to get contact records,

```
for(account acc:actlist){
system.debug(acc.contacts);
}
```